# Loading a CSV file with zingchart

Tags: javascript, csv, charts, zingchart

I'm trying to setup ZingChart so it will plot data from a local CSV file.

I have a working example using the csv and data-string attributes that renders the graph without issues:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="zingchart/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    zingchart.MODULESDIR = "zingchart/modules/";
  </script>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
  <script>
    var myConfig = {
      "type": "line",
      "csv":{
              "data-string":"Model|Highway|City_Ford 150|19|16_Mazda S3|30|21_Prius|42|35",
              "row-separator":"_",
              "separator":"|"
          }
    };

    zingchart.render({
      id: 'myChart',
      data: myConfig,
      height: 400,
      width: "100%"
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

However changing the csv so it links to a file instead raises an error:

```
  "csv": {
    "url": "zingchart/data01.csv"
  }
```

ZingChart error loading CSV file

[image: ZingChart error loading CSV file]

In the ZingChart tutorials there are links to JSFiddle so you can freely edit the javascript and see the results. On them I am also getting the same error screen if they are using the csv/url configuration option.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are making a cross-origin request to the ZingChart documentation website which does not allow you to use their resources on your site/local server. If you open up the console, you will see: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl - It's true, I get something along those lines: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/eballes/Work/backup/zingchart_test/zingchart/data01.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.ZC.A3.ajax @ VM514:1
VM514:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`. But I am not accessing their resources... as far as I know everything I have is (or should be) local.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl OK, understood. I got it working now. Basically I can't load a 'file://' as expressed  in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local). So I need to execute with Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files or just start a local http server on the machine. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you have ever used [GitHub | Gists](https://gist.github.com/), this website, http://bl.ocks.org, will allow you to view your Gists as long as you have an `index.html` file. The cool thing is they can load files over AJAX with relative paths. It may take a couple minutes for the page to change between updates to your code because the site caches the Gists periodically. In the following Gist, all I have is my index page and my data. [bl.ocks.org/03e006b2](https://bl.ocks.org/03e006b27f6a23aea434)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a cross-origin request to the ZingChart documentation website which does not allow you to use their resources on your site/local server.

If you open up the console, you will see:
`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Wherever your `index.html` page is located, you need a directory called *"zingchart"* with a file named *"data01.csv"*. Also, since this is an XHR request, you will need to either upload this on a website/server or start your own local Apache web server instance e.g. WAMP, LAMP, AMPPS, XAMPP.

Comment: The error was quite similar and everything had local scope: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/eballes/Work/backup/zingchart_test/zingchart/data01.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.ZC.A3.ajax @ VM514:1 VM514:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`   The root cause and possible solutions are explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local). Thanks a lot!